# git-annex created a monster that I cannot un-init

Tags: git, git-annex

I was going to explore git-annex, but it turns out it doesn't do what I need. That would be fine except that I initialized it on a repository that I'm using (stupid, I see that now) and now all my files have been replaced with symlinks.

I tried running `git-annex uninit` and it seemed like it was doing something:

```
unannex 2017/mapping/index.html ok
unannex 2017/mapping/slide_deck.md ok
unannex index.html ok
git-annex: Not fully uninitialized
Some annexed data is still left in .git/annex/objects/
This may include deleted files, or old versions of modified files.
```

But everything is still symlinks. What am I missing here? I even tried deleting the files in `2017/mapping` and copying new files over them but when I try to open them in Atom and edit them, when I save I get a permission error and when I go look I see that they're symlinks again. Even creating new files creates symlinks instead of files, which is confusing and frustrating.

How can I revert to where I was before all these symlinks?

I thought I'd solved the problem when I realized the git-annex daemon was still running, but I just went to commit my work and push and it is back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something [like `git annex get`](https://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/#index5h2)

You can also try enabling "[direct mode](https://git-annex.branchable.com/direct_mode/)" which should put your files back in the working tree instead of symlinks.